# How to avoid clang: No such file or directory error

Tags: r, macos, clang, anaconda, package

I am trying to install RPostgreSQL into my R instance.

I downloaded R with Anaconda, I also downloaded homebrew.

When I run, install.packages('RPostgreSQL') I get an error message that reads --

```
make: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang: No such file or directory
make: *** [RS-DBI.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘RPostgreSQL’
* removing ‘/Users/user/anaconda2/lib/R/library/RPostgreSQL’
```

Should I download this clang file?

Answer (score 13):

Try this command:

```
conda install clangxx_osx-64
```

And before open RStudio from Anaconda execute this:

```
export CONDA_BUILD_SYSROOT=$(xcrun --show-sdk-path)
```

Comment: Excellent solution.. this solved my problems with installing plotly as well. Thanks!

Comment: I second that - it's an excellent solution. For me it was unrelated to R studio - I encountered the problem while trying to update packages in plain R (anaconda). This now works! Thanks, Garmo!

Comment: For conda-forge users there are the meta-packages `c-compiler` and `cxx-compiler` that satisfy compiler needs platform independently.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on macOS then PLEASE always run `brew install go` instead.