# R package arules installation error on macos

Tags: r, anaconda, rstudio, macos-sierra, arules

I'm trying to install 'arules' package from within R console with the following 
* setup:
macOS Sierra v 10.12.6, R version 3.4.2, RStudio 1.1.383, Anaconda 5.0; anaconda client version 1.6.5, python 3.6.3

- From within R console with the command:

  ```
  install.packages("arules")
  ```
- Error output:

  ```
  install.packages("arules")
  trying URL 'https://cran.revolutionanalytics.com/src/contrib/arules_1.5-4.tar.gz'
  Content type 'application/octet-stream' length 1359205 bytes (1.3 MB)
  ==================================================
  downloaded 1.3 MB

  * installing *source* package ‘arules’ ...
  ** package ‘arules’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
  ** libs
  x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang -I/Users/alsabay/anaconda3/lib/R/include -DNDEBUG   -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.9 -I/Users/alsabay/anaconda3/include  -DNDEBUG -DNIMAPFN -fPIC  -march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe -I/Users/alsabay/anaconda3/include  -c arrayIndex.c -o arrayIndex.o
  make: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang: No such file or directory
  make: *** [arrayIndex.o] Error 1
  ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘arules’
  * removing ‘/Users/alsabay/anaconda3/lib/R/library/arules’

  The downloaded source packages are in ‘/private/var/folders/lc/_068llz1667dp1m75b_js4hr09p31n/T/RtmpObrwiG/downloaded_packages’
  Updating HTML index of packages in '.Library'
  Making 'packages.html' ... done
  Warning message:
  In install.packages("arules") :
    installation of package ‘arules’ had non-zero exit status
  ```

---

I have updated xcode command line tools as well to version 9.1, and I still get the same error. I have also tried installing it from RStudio with dependencies checked and i get the same error with the added compile errors on the dependency packages. I've run out of clues here, though I know it's some kind of a clang compile error but not sure about next steps. Please help.

Comment: Your R version uses clang 4.0, but Xcode 9.1 ships clang 7.0. Here is (hopefully) a solution https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/tools/

Comment: Finally got it to install. Thank you @MichaelHahsler for your help!

Comment: Check out my response [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47314899/how-to-avoid-clang-no-such-file-or-directory-error/47461936#47461936) for the same problem.

Comment: By "anaconda version 1.6.5" I think you mean "Anaconda 5.0, anaconda client version 1.6.5". See [Anaconda Release notes: Anaconda 5.0; Sept 26, 2017](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/release-notes#what-s-new-in-anaconda-5-0). Admittedly their multiple inconsistent numbering schemes are a real headache...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how i solved this issue using suggestion above

1. Download clang4 for macos according to the instructions on
       [cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/tools](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/tools).
2. Copy clang4 to /usr/local/clang4.
3. Create Makevars file in directory ~/.R with the
           following environment variables.

   ```
   CC=/usr/local/clang4/bin/clang
   CXX=/usr/local/clang4/bin/clang++
   LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/clang4/lib
   FC=/usr/local/bin/gfortran
   F77=/usr/local/bin/gfortran
   ```
4. Download and install gfortran-4.2.3.pkg from [cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/tools](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/tools) (this has an installer).
5. Start R console and type

   ```
   install.packages('arules')
   install.packages('arulesViz')
   ```